# C++ How to create a class object that loops and increments by one?

Tags: c++, class, loops, object, increment

I have three files and the output is what I want but it is not very elegant.

Is there any way to just have object `num (122)` and `num(554)` output the next number in sequence five times without having to `<< cout <<` every time?

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "number.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Number obj(122);

  cout << Nobj (122) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (123) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (124) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (125) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (126) << endl;

  cout << Nobj (554) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (555) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (556) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (557) << endl;
  cout << Nobj (558) << endl;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

class Number
{
public:
    Number(int numA);
    int operator ()(int numB);

    int numA;
};

#endif
```

number.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "number.h"

using namespace std;


Number::Number(int numC): numA(numC)
{}

int Number::operator()(int numB)
{
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 10)
    {
        return numB += 1;
        i++;
    }

}
```

output is:

```
123
124
125
126
127 
555
556
557
558
559
```

Edited:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    cout << Nobj (122+i) << endl;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    cout << Nobj (554+i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just write a loop?

Comment: Also, what is going on with your `operator()` code?  It's equivalent to `return numB + 1;`.

Comment: `i++` in the loop will be never executed, before that the method will return.

Comment: No point putting code in the comments where no-one will see it. Edit your question.

Comment: If the answer solved the problem mark it with the checkmark at the left side. If not and you solved the problem of your own, post another answer with the solution, and check this one as soon you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function may help you.

`inline void print_nums(const size_t start_num, const size_t loop_times) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < loop_times; ++i) {
        std::cout << (start_num + i);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent writing cout all the time you could overload the << operator

```
 friend std::ostream& ::operator <<(std::ostream& stream );
```

If you want to output objects in sequence you could for example:

- Make a wrapper class around class Number which is overloading << operator and storing all created Number objects
- Store single linked references/pointer in your Number-Class pointing to the next object(naive list or queue implementation). operator << will recursively call itself on the following object till its a nullptr